# Django admin select box options from model

Tags: django, admin

I have language category, tags and questions models. When adding question I want to select category and multiple tags in multiselect dropdown/checkbox from the admin panel
Here is my question model:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from languages.models import Language
from categories.models import Category
from tags.models import Tag


class Question(models.Model):
language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
tags = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

How can I achieve this in Django admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, I think you can use [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Like this:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from languages.models import Language
from categories.models import Category
from tags.models import Tag


class Question(models.Model):

    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Thanks, @nuddra, I will check it and see the result soon.

Comment: Correct, It is working @ruddra. Thanks a lot. Can you Plz tell me how can I implement the null value for language in the same scenario?

Comment: I think you can use `language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)`.